# Copying fields to a partner

Tags: python, odoo

Currently I'm overriding create and write to copy the fields onto the partner, is there a cleaner way of updating the partner on save?

```
@api.multi
def create(self, vals):
    if vals.get('allergy_ids'):
        self.add_partner_allergies(vals.get('allergy_ids')[0][2],
                                   vals.get('partner_id'))
    return super(Order, self).create(vals)


@api.multi
def write(self, vals, context=None):
    if vals.get('allergy_ids'):
        self.add_partner_allergies(
            vals.get('allergy_ids')[0][2],
            vals.get('partner_id', self.partner_id.id))

    return super(Order, self).write(vals)

def add_partner_allergies(self, allergy_ids, partner_id):
    """
    Populates the partner with allergies from the order for the future.
    :param allergy_ids:
    :param partner_id:
    :return:
    """
    domain = [('id', '=', partner_id)]
    partners = self.env['res.partner'].search(domain)
    allergies = copy.deepcopy(allergy_ids)
    partner_allergies = partners[0].allergy_ids.ids
    allergies = list(set(itertools.chain(allergies,
                                         partner_allergies)))

    partners.write({'allergy_ids': [(6, False, allergies)]})
```

It seems rather excessive to have to handle it with this much code.

Note that the data isn't relational, the partner contains the aggregate of all the allergies that have saved onto their orders, so that we can set defaults on following orders. But it shouldn't be that case that if we delete allergies from the partner, the allergies should disappear from all their orders.